# The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, objectinputstream, buildpath

I have downloaded Eclipse and tried to create a sample servlet program but I got following error

> The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have configured build path correctly.
I am using Java 8 and Apache Tomcat 7 and libraries for both are referenced correctly.

Problem is specifically for Java EE only. Ordinarily Java SE projects are running fine.

Comment: What specific Java 8 version is this about?

Comment: I am getting the same exception with both jdk and jre Version 8 Update 91.

Comment: Red Hat issue related to this : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2294701

Comment: @İbrahimGürses I can't access it due to login restrictions. It would be kind if you could post the conclusion or solution if there is any.

Comment: @flob: The suggested resolution is "Consider precompiling JSPs as a workaround". There is also a link to a reopened bug report (1223609) and note that says "ecj is an older version that does not support java 8". I don't know what to make of that. There was no problem with Java 8 Update 77 AFAIK.

Comment: The following bug was resolved on May 2 as "not an issue" with this comment: "Closing as not an issue. This should be resolved by upgrading to latest versions of Tomcat." https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8155588. A customer submitted workaround says "the only work around is to go back older JDK/JRE version and pray that the glitch will go away with the new release".

Comment: In a comment in this Red Hat issue, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1336481, the following vulnerability is mentioned: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-3427. It is also in Oracle Critical Patch Update Advisory - April 2016: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/security-advisory/cpuapr2016v3-2985753.html.

Comment: I have same problem with JDK 1.8.0_191 . Then I have change it 1.8.0_162 and its working now

Answer (score 42):

Something happened in Java 8 Update 91 that broke existing JSP code. That seems pretty clear. Here is a sample of similar questions and bug reports:

- [Unable to compile JSP file with JDK1.8.0_92](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36981733/407651)
- [Spring MVC - Unable to compile class for JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36956912/407651)
- [Unable to access CloudPlatform Client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37184043/407651)
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8155588 (closed as "not an issue")
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8155223 (closed as "not an issue")
- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2294701
- https://alluxio.atlassian.net/browse/ALLUXIO-1956
- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CWD-4729
- https://community.exoplatform.com/portal/intranet/forum/topic/topic991e097d9e45345236bb2bd1920a4c68
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2533 (from a comment: "This is really looking like a JDK bug")
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1337940 (comment 2 mentions the change to `java.io.ObjectInputStream` in Update 91 that "made it incompatible with RHEL6's current ECJ version")
- https://github.com/mit-cml/appinventor-sources/issues/814
- https://community.oracle.com/thread/3953395

All these are about problems with Java 8 Update 91 (or later) that are not present when using earlier JRE/JDK versions.

---

The following OpenJDK changeset from 22 January 2016 appears to be related: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/rev/32f64c19b5fb (commit message "8144430: Improve JMX connections"). The changeset seems to be related to this vulnerability, https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-3427, which is mentioned in a comment to this Red Hat bug report, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1336481.

The Update 91 release notes document mentions JDK-8144430 (non-public ticket): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u91-relnotes-2949462.html.

In "Oracle Critical Patch Update Advisory - April 2016", the CVE-2016-3427 vulnerability is mentioned: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/security-advisory/cpuapr2016v3-2985753.html.

Comment: facing the same issue but once I move to tomcat 7 things are working fine..using jdk8_121

Comment: @dom, in the question it says "I am using Java 8 and Apache Tomcat 7". So what do you mean by "once I move to tomcat 7"?

Answer (score 8):

You simply need to upgrade your Tomcat version, to Tomcat 8.0.xx.
**Java8 <-> Tomcat8**

This is the configuration that I have been using and it has always worked out well
[image: JDK version]
[image: Tomcat versions]

Comment: To me it seems like a bug in Java 8 Update 91. I doubt that upgrading Tomcat will fix the issue for everyone. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36981733/unable-to-compile-jsp-file-with-jdk1-8-0-92#comment62126450_36981733-.

Comment: @user3891270: Does this answer help? Does it work if you upgrade to Tomcat 8?

Comment: Runtime Environments->Add->Apache->till 7 version i could find but 8th version of apache is not shown.How to add it externally.Please  help me bro

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala what version of Eclipse are you using? I suggest you to use new versions; they are faster, they still support old versions of java and more stable. You should find Apache 7 from version Kepler (4.3) on.  https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: @mzjn it seems that from Update 92 on, the issue is solved; we still need to have a compatible version of Tomcat.

Comment: @IsmaelSarmento yeah I just resolved it by installing new version of eclipse jee

Answer (score 2):

**Using the latest 7.x Tomcat (currently 7.0.69) solved the problem** for me.

We did also try a workaround in a old eclipse bug, maybe that did it's part to solve the problem, too?

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=67414

Workaround:

- Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs
- Uncheck selected JRE
- Click OK (this step may be optional?)
- Check JRE again

Comment: I am upgrading to tomcat-7.0.70, and i am seeing the problem in some cases.  I use SUSE Linux version 12 and all is copacetic, but i have an older machine on version 11 SP 3, and that one still has the error with JDK_1.8.0_91.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this question was a year ago but I recently got this problem as well.

So what I did :

1. Update tomcat 7 to tomcat 8.
2. Update to the latest java (java 1.8.0_141).
3. Update the JRE System Library in *Project > Properties > Java Build Path*. 
   Make sure it has the latest version which in my case is jre1.8.0_141
   (before it was the previous version jre1.8.0_111)

When I did the first two steps it still doesn't remove the error so the last step is important. It didn't automatically change the build path for jre.

Answer (score 2):

Reason :
Old versions of Tomcat 6 JSP compiler don't seem to be aware of JDK 8 constant pool enhancements - eg. method handles. New code in JDK 8u is using a method handle instead of creating an anonymous class. This will cause the method handle to be listed in the constant pool and the eclipse compiler will choke on this - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56613

Answer (score 1):

same problem with me. This is not a solution but a workaround, which worked for me:
Buildpath->Configure buildpath->Libraries-> Here remove the JRE system library pointing to JRE8 and add JRE system library for JRE7.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

*Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Installed JREs*,
select a different JRE

maybe this JDK edition is not suitable:

[image]

---

So try this one instead:

[image]

Problem solved!

Comment: Exercise caution when downgrading -- it's worth noting that there are many known security vulnerabilities in prior versions of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to tomcat 7.0.70 resolved the issue for me

Comment: Change the Tomcat server, I upgraded to Tomcat 8

Answer (score 1):

I am using Google appengine java sdk and was facing similar issue. I had to add

```
<runtime>java8</runtime>
```

in appengine-web.xml file to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. I had Jdk1.7.0.79. Then I updated it with Jdk8.0.120. Then the problem solved. After successful completion of upgraded jdk. Go to project->clean. It will rebuild the project and all red alert will be eliminated.