# Unable to access CloudPlatform Client

Tags: apache-cloudstack, cloud-platform

I've installed Apache CloudStack 4.7.0.0 and after startup, when accessing the CloudPlatform Web Console, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
type Exception report
message
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.24 logs.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
```

Does anyone know why this would occur?

Cheers,

Michele

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was more of a workaround than a resolution. Downgrade the OpenJdk to version 1.8.0.77.

From this thread ([The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963248/the-type-java-io-objectinputstream-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenc)) I picked up that it may be a java issue so I reinstalled with the previous version of Open Jdk (1.8.0.77) and the CloudPlatform was able to compile the jsps.

Thanks @MZJN

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on 1.7 of Java. 1.8 is work in progress and you may encounter some issues there.

http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-release-notes/en/4.7.0/upgrade/upgrade_notes.html

Consider using mailing lists if you need help.