# Issues regarding package in java

Tags: java

I have been using java for last few days,I am getting an issue form last few days.
When i am trying to create a class in servlet the package section is showing the following error "**

- **The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is
  indirectly referenced from required .class files**

  while i try to comment out the
- **import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;**

**" section the error is going, but for that i cant extend the httpservlet class. please help me out for this issue.

This image shows the error:

[image: This image shows the error]

Comment: Make sure you have servlet-api jar in classpath. Also, check if you are using JDK and not JRE in eclipse project classpath.

Comment: yes i have set everything still the problem remains the same.

Comment: add project libraries to deployment descriptor

Answer (score 1):

Include servlet-api-3.1.jar in your dependencies.

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Gradle

```
configurations {
    provided
}
sourceSets {
    main { compileClasspath += configurations.provided }
}
dependencies {
    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: The following links may be useful,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963248/the-type-java-io-objectinputstream-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenc