# Java - Multiple markers at this line - java.io.ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, objectinputstream

I have a test class.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class TestWindow extends JFrame{



}
```

I use eclipse. This class gives an error on line 1.
Error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
- The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
```

Why i see this error. Normally it should work. How can i fix this error ?

Comment: I think you have a confused Eclipse, or a damaged Eclipse or Java installation. The compiler cannot find the ".class" file for a class that should be in the standard Java class library.  Try restarting Eclipse, cleaning the project, restarting Eclipse with the "--clean" option.  If none of these help, consider reinstalling.

Comment: I've tried all your advice. Now I'm reinstalling elipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link : [The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963248/the-type-java-io-objectinputstream-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenc)

I guess it will answer your query.